# warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Tags: 6

I am running drupal 6 and I get this warning on every page.

```
warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /var/www/my-website/includes/common.inc on line 915.
```

And this is what I have from lines 914 to 917 in `common.inc` file

```
// Custom strings work for English too, even if locale module is disabled.
if (isset($custom_strings[$langcode][$string])) {    /* Line: 915 */
  $string = $custom_strings[$langcode][$string];
}
```

What could be the possible reasons for the warning and how to get rid of it? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit:**
   This warning appears only for anonymous users and it is not visible for authenticated users.

Comment: Did you recently install any modules?  Try turning off the modules you have enabled one by one.  Each time you turn off a module, clear the cache.  Then check to see if the error still appears.  Once you find which module is causing the problem, edit your question with the new information.

Comment: @PatrickKenny: Thx for your comment. I will do that.

Comment: @PatrickKenny: I disabled all the modules one by one and cleared all cache everytime but still no luck. The warning still appears on all the pages.

Comment: Have you tried switching back to a default theme (if you are using a custom one). Does the error persist? Have you defined a new region in your theme .info file and not included it in your page.tpl.php?

Comment: Looks like a translation / Multilanguage issue perhaps translating an object or similar instead of string.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed the problem. I think this will help you. For me it works perfectly:

BEFORE:

```
// Custom strings work for English too, even if locale module is disabled.
if (isset($custom_strings[$langcode][$string])) {
  $string = $custom_strings[$langcode][$string];
}
```

AFTER:

```
// Custom strings work for English too, even if locale module is disabled.
if ($custom_strings[$langcode] && isset($custom_strings[$langcode][$string])) {
  $string = $custom_strings[$langcode][$string];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you still need help solving the issue, you can try setting your own error handler to print a debug_backtrace to see exactly where the source of error is.

More details: http://blog.ryantan.net/2012/12/debugging-illegal-offset-type-in-isset-or-empty-in-for-drupal-7/

Comment: There is Devel module.